# MySQL 8.0 trx_sys_mutex wait time spike

Tags: mysql, innodb

During an outage on our website we observed many SQL in MySQL slow query log with Lock_time: > 100 seconds
The queries that had long Lock_time were simple (below copied from slow query log)

```
SET timestamp=1599242815;
select `user`.`first_name`, `user`.`last_name`, `user`.`email` from `user` where `user`.`user_id` = <>;
# Time: 2020-09-04T18:13:12.674309Z
# User@Host: <>[<>] @  [<>]  Id: 2128691
# Query_time: 359.872340  Lock_time: 223.442795 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 1
```

user_id is the auto generated primary key of this table (unsigned int). All other SQL found in slow query logs were similar (direct access via PrimaryKey)

The queries found in slow query log were random (not specific to particular table group). No other long-running high row scan query at this time and no long-running write transaction in particular.

Below is what we found in performance_insights
[image: trx_sys_mutex wait time spike]

How do we find out why the wait on trx_sys_mutex spiked suddenly? We have never seen such behavior in last 5 years of the operation.

MySQL 8.0.19 on AWS RDS: 32 core machine, using innodb engine for tables. The time shown in image is in IST, RDS automated Backup window is 10 hours before the incident time

Comment: The slow query log shows the query _after_ the lines with the time, user, and query time. I think you're looking at the wrong query.

Comment: Hi Bill, you are right, however I pasted the query at the top manually while writing the question so it's the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

A `SELECT` query doesn't require any row locks, unless you use transaction isolation level SERIALIZABLE. So it can only be a metadata lock. Every query requires a metadata lock, and this can be blocked by any other session holding onto that metadata lock. Any ALTER/DROP/TRUNCATE/RENAME TABLE statement for example, or LOCK TABLES.

I also see the Query_time was 6 minutes (359.87 seconds), over two minutes of which was after the lock wait was done.

I assume `user.user_id` the primary key of that table? So it looked up a single row by primary key and took *minutes* to do it? That's implausible for it to take so long.

That only happens when the host has become unresponsive, in my experience. It has nothing to do with your SQL query.

I'd consider other possibilities:

- A noisy neighbor problem. That is, another RDS container on the same host did something that caused the system load to spike. Unfortunately, AWS shares hosts with containers belonging to different accounts, so this sort of thing can happen and you never know who was responsible.
- Something happened on the host, unrelated to any RDS container. Perhaps an OS upgrade or failover or something. Again, this will be outside of your control and you have no way of checking.

Can you run the same query again, searching the same table for the same value on the same RDS instance, and have it take little time? That would point to a temporary problem on the host, not a problem with your query.

As I said, any query requires a metadata lock. This lock must be acquired which means there's a nonzero amount of code to check that a metadata lock is not present to block your query. Normally this is so quick that you never notice it, but if the host is so overloaded that normal operations take minutes, even this quick check for metadata lock could stretch out.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Bill, the query runs < 5 ms when run independently, or in normal scenario. The problem was temporary and lasted only 4 mins and resolved automatically itself. We just wanted to get down to the root cause, we had contacted AWS support however didn't receive anything useful from them. Your comment on OS failover etc. looks a suspect. We will check more with AWS support on this aspect.